# DES Encryption in PHP and C#

Tags: c#, php, encryption

I'm trying to achive the same DES encription that I've in an C# code but in PHP.

The C# code looks like the following:

```
public static string EncriptarCadena(string strEncriptar)
{
    DESCryptoServiceProvider provider;

    MemoryStream stream;
    CryptoStream stream2;
    string str2;
    string str = "29393651";
    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[] { 0x45, 50, 0xa5, 0x18, 0x67, 0x58, 0xac, 0xba };
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0];
    try
    {
        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str.Substring(0, 8));
        provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strEncriptar);
        stream = new MemoryStream();
        stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, provider.CreateEncryptor(bytes, buffer2), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        stream2.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream2.FlushFinalBlock();
        str2 = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        str2 = "";
    }
    finally
    {
        provider = null;
        stream = null;
        stream2 = null;
    }
    return str2;
}
```

And the code that I've done till now in PHP is the following:

```
function encrypt($string) {
    //Key
    $key = "29393651";
    $ivArray=array( 0x45, 50, 0xa5, 0x18, 0x67, 0x58, 0xac, 0xba );
    $iv=null;
    foreach ($ivArray as $element)
        $iv.=CHR($element);

    echo "Key: $key    IV: $iv<br>";

    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

    return base64_encode($encrypted_string);
}
```

But I can't find where is the problem, as they don't give the same result for the same input.

Any help will be very welcome :)

Comment: You're setting CBC mode in the PHP code; I don't see a call to set CBC mode in the C# code? AFAIK, most libraries default to ECB.

Comment: Hi staticsan, I checked that the default mode in C# it's CBC, anyway I've tried changing in the php code between all the available modes (ecb,cbc,cfb,ofb,nofb,stream) and didn't work either :(

Comment: Did you verify that the input bytes is exactly the same?  The c# one is doing a substring and making it utf8, and the php one is just looking at $string

Comment: Hi superfro, I've try both with normal string, or converting it to a char array and folding it, that at the end I guess in php is the same, at least I got the same result in both parameters in php, but still different from C# :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29). PHP internally pads the data to be encrypted with binary NULLs `\x00` by default which is definitively not the default padding mode in .NET (most likely they use PKCS7 padding by default).

Comment: Hey Stefan, I fixed it and it works! :) It was the problem, I've implemented PKCS7 padding for the input in php and it works properly.
Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much guys. Helped me with same problem. 
PKCS7 padding here: [How to add/remove PKCS7 padding from an AES encrypted string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314901/how-to-add-remove-pkcs7-padding-from-an-aes-encrypted-string/7324793#7324793) just change ecb to cbc

here is a short snapshot i used:

```
$key = "29393651";
$iv = $key;
$pass_enc = $mypassword;
$block = mcrypt_get_block_size('des', 'cbc');
$pad = $block - (strlen($pass_enc) % $block);
$pass_enc .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
$pass_enc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $pass_enc, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
$pass_enc = base64_encode ($pass_enc);
```