# Android AES with no padding decryption, unknown characters 'NUL' at the end of string

Tags: java, php, android, encryption, cryptography

I've following code to decrypt the files in Java which are encrypted via PHP `mcrypt` function.

```
private String iv = "MYKEYHERE";//Dummy iv (CHANGE IT!)
private String SecretKey = "MYKEYHERE";//Dummy secretKey (CHANGE IT!)

private byte[] decrypt(String code)
{
    byte[] decrypted = null;
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");
        if(code == null || code.length() == 0)
            throw new Exception("Empty string");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);

        decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decrypted;
}

private static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
    if (str==null) {
        return null;
    } else if (str.length() < 2) {
        return null;
    } else {
        int len = str.length() / 2;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            try {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

**and I'm reading and writing the files from SDCARD as**

```
String encyptedData = readFileFromSDCard(params[0]);

byte[] decryptedByteArray = decrypt(encyptedData);

File rootFile = new File(Constants.folioTempLocation+params[1]);
rootFile.mkdirs();

File outFile = new File(rootFile,  new File(params[0]).getName());
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
//IOUtils.write(decryptedByteArray, out);
out.write(decryptedByteArray);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

There is no problem with decryption and writing files back to SD_CARD. But I'm **getting unknown characters at the end of each file** which is restricting the whole decrypted file to work properly.

I'm attaching screenshot of unknown characters concatenated to end of string. I'm also attaching an [encrypted_html_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2JMyLa3sbeKb1ZkSDNJRk1Zbnc/edit?usp=sharing) for anyone want to test the code using this file.

Screenshot
[image: sample image]

Comment: @Andrew T. thanks for edit, do you have idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Actually I don't know since I haven't encountered it myself. If you test it on other files, is it always returning 5 NULL characters?

Comment: @AndrewT. the `NUL` characters are arbitrary, it varies from 2 to 10 at the end of string. Notepad++ shows this as `NUL` characters but Notepad shows it as blank spaces.

Comment: It is a [null control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), represent as 0x00 in byte. Since there is no problem with decryption, I suspect the encryption artifact. In any case, probably it can be fixed by removing trailing nulls after decrypting the file, before saving the file.

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks for the research, can you post the answer how to remove trailing `NUL` coz I've also tried to trim `byte[]` from end but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't know the cause of the problem, I can only provide a work-around to remove the trailing nulls (NUL).

```
public static byte[] removeTrailingNulls(byte[] source) {
    int i = source.length;
    while (source[i - 1] == 0x00) {
        i--;
    }

    byte[] result = new byte[i];
    System.arraycopy(source, 0, result, 0, i);

    return result;
}
```

Try it just after decrypting the file

```
byte[] decryptedByteArray = removeTrailingNulls(decrypt(encyptedData));
```

**Warning:
This may affect the performance (especially on mobile device) since it uses nearly twice the memory usage.**

**This workaround is not perfect since it will always remove trailing nulls, regardless of original data. Use at your own risk**

Comment: Works like charm, but do i need to worry if i do the process in background thread in devices having primary memory more than 1GB.

Comment: The warning is more like a general warning for future viewers: not all devices have more than 1GB, and not all apps can use all of them ;)

Comment: What if the real data has trailing zero bytes? Your code cannot distinguish between those zero bytes and padding bytes.

Comment: @Greg I know, and that's why I say  "workaround", not the "proper way". Nonetheless, I will leave this answer here, and I have added another warning for that. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3):

CBC is a block mode and must be used with proper padding scheme.

PHP's [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) uses [zero padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#Zero_padding) - it appends `\0` characters to the input data to make it length a multiple of block size. Obviously you get these zero bytes back when decryption.

The mycrypt page has an example of how to implement proper PKCS#7 padding scheme in the user comments. Among other [mcrypt padding](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mcrypt%20padding%20is%3Aquestion) questions [How to add/remove PKCS7 padding from an AES encrypted string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314901/how-to-add-remove-pkcs7-padding-from-an-aes-encrypted-string) provides a similar example.