# Php and cryptoJS IV

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

I encrypt and decrypt data using PHP like this:

```
<?php 
function encrypt($data, $secret){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    return base64_encode($iv.openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $secret, 0, $iv));
}

function decrypt($encryptedData, $secret){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $data = base64_decode($encryptedData);
    $iv = substr($data, 0, $iv_size);
    return openssl_decrypt(substr($data, $iv_size), 'aes-256-cbc', $secret, 0, $iv);
}
?>
```

I am now wanting to be able to encrypt my data locally (identically to the PHP method) using [Crypto-JS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/#AES). I have done the same as above to get the key and iv:

```
var key = '<?php echo $secret;?>';
var iv = '<?php echo base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND));?>';
```

Now when using [Crypto-JS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/#AES) I have tried to encrypt using:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text), CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key), { iv: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv) });
```

But I also need to store the IV like I do with PHP So I have added:

```
var withIV = iv+encrypted;
```

but that is not encoded. So I have added:

```
CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(withIV));
```

But this is not the same encoding as the PHP above for some reason?

Comment: don't dump text from php into a json context directly. while the b64 stuff is reasonably safe, that key could contain js metachars. you should be using json_encode: `var foo = <?php echo json_encode($foo); ?>;` so you're ALWAYS generating valid javascript.

Comment: @MarcB would you be able to link me to something with more info on what you are talking about? I haven't got the foggiest why what I am doing is bad. :(

Comment: php: `$name = "Miles O'Brien";`, which you then echo into JS: `var js = 'Miles O'Brien';` - oops, syntax error, and now your js code block is dead. using json_encode would produce the proper/valid `var js = 'Miles O\'Brien';`

Comment: Ahhh!! Sorry stupid of me! I will start doing that. Any ideas on the encoding question above?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I encrypt data with CryptoJS:

```
function encrypt(str, key, iv) {
    var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key);
    var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(str, key, { iv: iv }).toString();
};
```

In PHP, I decrypt the encrypted string produced by that function using this line of code:

```
openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data_string, "AES-128-CBC", hex2bin($key_hex_string), 0, hex2bin($iv_hex_string));
```

I suppose you could encode/decode the encrypted data in base 64 instead of hexadecimal if you wanted to. Anyway, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have trouble concatenating IV and the ciphertext in CryptoJS. This is rather easy, because CryptoJS' native binary data format (`WordArray`) supports the `concat` function:

```
var ivWords = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv); // WordArray instance
var plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text); // WordArray instance
var keyWords = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key); // WordArray instance
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, keyWords, { iv: ivWords }); // CipherParams instance

var ct = ivWords.clone().concat(encrypted.ciphertext); // WordArray instance
var ct = ct.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); // string instance
console.log(ct);
```

```js
// example data
var iv = "0102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f";
var text = "text";
var key = "1112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f";

// actual code
var ivWords = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv); // WordArray instance
var plaintext = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(text); // WordArray instance
var keyWords = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(key); // WordArray instance
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, keyWords, { iv: ivWords }); // CipherParams instance

var ct = ivWords.clone().concat(encrypted.ciphertext); // WordArray instance
var ct = ct.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64); // string instance
output.innerHTML = ct;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

This would produce the same output as

```
base64_encode($iv.openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $secret, 0, $iv));
```

as long as `iv` is actually hex-encoded string with that contains the same bytes as the decoded version in `$iv`. The same must be true for `text` (except for the encoding), `key` and `$data`, `$secret`, respectively.

Comment: Awesome!! Is there a way to generate the iv similarly to how I generate it using php `mcrypt_create_iv()`? Because if I generate by say `var iv = "<?php echo mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);?>"` And I use the same `text` twice it will return the same `ct`?

Comment: Well, you need to generate a fresh (and unpredictable) IV for each encryption. `Math.random()` is not random enough for cryptographic properties. See my answer under the following link for more information: [A: Encrypting with CryptoJS and decrypt with php: What is the use of the IV?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31651483/1816580)

Comment: Thank you for that! I am getting the error `Invalid array length` on this line: `var ct = ivWords.clone().concat(encrypted.ciphertext);` ?

Comment: Try it without the `.clone()`. I've looked into the function and it seems to be implemented incorrectly.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I've added a runnable snippet.

Comment: also If i run the output of your snippet with my php decode function there is no output. - `echo decrypt("AQIDBAUGBwgJCgsMDQ4P8/K4xC8WwbHJjyoSBUxshw==","1112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f")`

Comment: You're not using the same key. I'm using a 32 character hex-encoded key, which is actually 16 bytes long (128 bit). It seems your PHP code isn't parsing the key as hex, but instead uses it directly.

Comment: So should I remove all the `CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(`?

Comment: I don't know how your key looks, but if it is randomly generated (recommended) and written without any encoding to the JavaScript block, then it is most likely a key with some bytes missing and therefore broken.

Comment: ahgg I am so stressed out by this!! I do not understand why none of this is working :(

Comment: here is the php without generating a random iv and using the same one you preset http://pastebin.com/7yS527au

Comment: Your IV is too long. Don't confuse binary strings and encoded strings.