# How to decrypt a cryptojs text in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

I use following code in JS to encrypt my data:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const IV_LENGTH = 16; // For AES, this is always 16

export function encrypt(text, key) {
 let iv = crypto.randomBytes(IV_LENGTH);
 let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', new Buffer(key), iv);
 let encrypted = cipher.update(text);
 encrypted = Buffer.concat([encrypted, cipher.final()]);
 return iv.toString('hex') + ':' + encrypted.toString('hex');
}
```

I have tried to decrypt it in PHP (with pack('H*',.) etc but I can't find a solution to decode it in PHP. All the time I get the error that the IV is to long because I am not able to transform it back in PHP.

Do you have an idea how I can decrypt it in PHP?

Thank you very much and I wish a nice weekend!

Comment: look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509934/encrypt-with-cryptojs-and-decrypt-with-php

Comment: Are you really sure the IV is 128-bit (16 bytes) considering you're using aes-**256** encryption?

Comment: @RocketNuts Yes I'am sure and it works also with decrypting with JS.But thanks for the response.

Comment: @عارفبنالأزرق Hi thanks for the hint but this is a total other process then that what I use.... So I can't get it work..

Comment: @RocketNuts The 256 in AES-256 refers to the key size, not the block size.  AES has a fixed block size of 128 bits.  Just FYI :)

Comment: @LukePark You're right, thanks!