# How to get the same result with Node.js and PHP-mcrypt using TripleDES encryption?

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, openssl, mcrypt

This is 3DES using `crypto` (base on OpenSSL) in native Node.js.

```
var secretKey         = "efd77bed61e8fdd0437df1ac";
var enchding          = 'hex';
var text              = 'This is test.';
var cipher            = modules.crypto.createCipher('des-ede3-cbc', secretKey);
var cryptedPassword   = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', enchding) + cipher.final(enchding);
```

> output is : af4ee52e0227fe40ab2e7ddd72fb1137

---

But I used online PHP-mcrypt encrypt tool ([link here](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/)).

Key is `efd77bed61e8fdd0437df1ac`

Algorithm is `Tripledes`, mode is `CBC` and output using `Hexa`.

> output is : d4b374b7ac8df7883ab1d58c7db0b0cc

---

Why does both of these are different results?

And how can I get the same result using `crypto` in Node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

- [`crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password) uses a password not a key. The actual key will be derived from that password. It seems that you want to use a key instead of a password, so you need to use [`crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv).
- PHP's mcrypt module only applies zero padding, but node.js' crypto module only applies PKCS#5/PKCS#7 padding. You should use PKCS#7 padding in PHP like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27590539/1816580). (used in the example code)
- You have to use the same IV in both node.js and PHP. Usually a random IV is generated and prepended to the ciphertext. During decryption it must be sliced off and used. (not included in the example code)

**node.js**

```js
var crypto = require('crypto');

var secretKey         = new Buffer("efd77bed61e8fdd0437df1ac", "utf8");
var iv                = new Buffer("\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
var enchding          = 'hex';
var text              = 'This is test.';
var cipher            = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', secretKey, iv);
var cryptedPassword   = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', enchding) + cipher.final(enchding);

console.log(cryptedPassword);
```

output:

```
4e91635045f42185831403057ef16749
```

**PHP**

```php
function pkcs7pad($plaintext, $blocksize)
{
    $padsize = $blocksize - (strlen($plaintext) % $blocksize);
    return $plaintext . str_repeat(chr($padsize), $padsize);
}

$pt = pkcs7pad('This is test.', 8);
$iv = '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0';
$key = 'efd77bed61e8fdd0437df1ac';

$ct = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_3DES, $key, $pt, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo bin2hex($ct);
```

output:

```
4e91635045f42185831403057ef16749
```

---

It seems you want to encrypt passwords. Passwords should never be encrypted. Use a good hashing solution like PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt and verify the password by hashing it again.

Comment: How do I tell `node.js` to use `PKCS#5`?

Comment: @majidarif [PKCS#5 and PKCS#7 paddings are equivalent](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/9044/13022) (actually, there is no such   thing as PKCS#5 padding for AES). node.js uses PKCS#7 by default