# PHP encryption and CryptoJS decryption

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptojs

I have a problem when decrypting (using CryptoJs) my PHP encrypted data.
Here is my PHP encryption:

```
function encrypt($pure_string, $encryption_key, $iv) {
    $encrypted_string = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $encryption_key, utf8_encode($pure_string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    return $encrypted_string;
}

function cripto()
{
    $crypto_key = "230e8cb8c43d532f389ff0e2b5337919";
    $data_to_encrypt = "Data to encrypt";

    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    $ciphertext = $this->encrypt($data_to_encrypt, $crypto_key, $iv);
    return array("iv" => pack('H*', $iv), "chipertext" => base64_encode($ciphertext),"key" => $crypto_key);

}
```

And here is my JavaScript code (the result of php crypto function is stored in encrypted variable):

```
var ciphertext = <?php echo '"'.$encrypted["ciphertext"].'"'; ?>;
var iv = <?php echo '"'.$encrypted["iv"].'"'; ?>;
var crypto_key = <?php echo '"'.$encrypted["key"].'"'; ?>;

iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);
ciphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext);

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, crypto_key,{ iv: iv });
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

My decrypted value is always an empty string and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

- PHP uses Zero padding (padding of 0-15 bytes of 0x00), but CryptoJS uses PKCS#7 padding by default. Those are incompatible.
- CryptoJS' `decrypt()` function expects a CipherParams object which you can simply emulate by passing an object with the `ciphertext` property set.

Together:

```
iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);
ciphertext = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext);

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ ciphertext: ciphertext }, crypto_key, {
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
});
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

Don't forget to include [pad-zeropadding-min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CryptoStore/crypto-js/3.1.2/build/components/pad-zeropadding-min.js).

---

Keep in mind that JavaScript cryptography has its [problems for justification](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/). You really should be using SSL, because without SSL, this is just obfuscation (key is sent along with the ciphertext).

It would be better to do the [PKCS#7 padding in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27590539/1816580) and keep the default in CryptoJS.