# Blowfish encryption - encrypted in php and java, I got different encrypted values

Tags: java, php, encryption, blowfish

**The encryption test data:**

```
key: 'ABC';
data:'1234567';
algorithm:  MCRYPT_BLOWFISH;
mode: MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;
```

**PHP code**

```
$key  = 'ABC';
$data = '1234567';
$alg  = MCRYPT_BLOWFISH;
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;

$encrypted_data = mcrypt_encrypt($alg, $key, $data, $mode);

$phpgeneratedtoken  = base64_encode($encrypted_data);

print "PHP generated token: " . $phpgeneratedtoken."   ";
// return
// In6uDpDqt1g=

// Decode the token just generated by php

$decoded = mcrypt_decrypt($alg,$key,base64_decode("In6uDpDqt1g="),$mode);
print "Decoded from php generated token:" . $decoded."    ";

//return
//1234567

// This is the encrypted token generated by java with same key and value
$javageneratedtoken  = "Cg8qY4gRMaI=";

// Decode the token generated by Java
$decoded = mcrypt_decrypt($alg,$key,base64_decode("Cg8qY4gRMaI="),$mode);
print "Decoded from Java Generated token: " . $decoded."    ";
// return
// 1234567

// Both tokens generated by java and php, are decrypted back to the same value.
```

**Java Code:**

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class BlowfishTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        encrypt("1234567");
        decrypt("In6uDpDqt1g=");
    }

    private static void encrypt(String password) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyData = ("ABC").getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] hasil = cipher.doFinal(password.getBytes());
        System.out.println(new BASE64Encoder().encode(hasil));
    }

    private static void decrypt(String string) throws Exception {
        byte[] keyData = ("ABC").getBytes();
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, "Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("blowfish/ecb/nopadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] hasil = cipher.doFinal(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(string));
        System.out.println(new String(hasil));
    }
}
```

**The PHP generated encrypted value is:** `In6uDpDqt1g=`.

**The Java generated encrypted value is:** `Cg8qY4gRMaI=`.

The issue is at Java Code's

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("blowfish");
```

**I need to find a way to make my PHP generated encrypted value the same as the Java generated encrypted value.**

Both encrypted values I can decrypt them back in PHP. Both encrypted values I could decrypt them back in java too, ONLY IF I set,

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("blowfish/ecb/nopadding");
```

But when I try to decrypt PHP encrypted value, `In6uDpDqt1g=`, in Java.

If I set,

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("blowfish");
```

I got the error:

> "Given final block not properly padded".

The problem is I am supposed to use PHP to encrypt value, and my client would use java to decrypt value. With the setup `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("blowfish")` to decrypt my value.

So I want to find a way that I should use PHP to get the same encrypted value as Java, with `Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish")`, would get.

If there is no such solution, then I would have to ask my client to change his java codes to use

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("blowfish/ecb/nopadding");
```

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: Why don't use use `Cipher.getInstance("blowfish/cbc/pkcs5padding")`, transmit the IV and [use proper padding in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27590539/1816580).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I find my answer. I need to change my php code to

```
$key  = 'ABC';
$data = '1234567';
$alg  = MCRYPT_BLOWFISH;
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;

$blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size('blowfish', 'ecb'); // get block size 
$pkcs = $blocksize - (strlen($data) % $blocksize); // get pkcs5 pad length 
$data.= str_repeat(chr($pkcs), $pkcs);

$encrypted_data = mcrypt_encrypt($alg, $key, $data, $mode);

$phpgeneratedtoken  = base64_encode($encrypted_data);

print "PHP generated token: " . $phpgeneratedtoken."   ";
// return
// Cg8qY4gRMaI=
```