# Encryption AES 128

Tags: php, encryption, aes, pkcs#7, ecb

I've been asked at work to implement a request for a simple web service with the following instructions:

**AES encryption:

Type: ECB

Size: 128bits

Padding Mode: PKCS7

key: 9b6018215942b2e1da3797d3394779bf**

In the docs (just a given example) they say that for the string:

> 2874838-49

The encryption process must generate:

> BEE361962A1802A7BA2AD328DAE8B291

I've been searching a lot for something like this, but none of the solutions (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314901/how-to-add-remove-pkcs7-padding-from-an-aes-encrypted-string), [here](https://gist.github.com/Halama/5956871) [here](https://gist.github.com/RiANOl/1077723/fb7add28bdb7d9829a134ed45edc049453891797), etc...) given helped me achieving the example result given.

This was the last thing I tried now:

```
function aes128Encrypt($data, $key) {
  $padding = 32 - (strlen($data) % 32);
  $data .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
  return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
}
$data = "2874838-49";
$key = "9b6018215942b2e1da3797d3394779bf";    
echo aes128Encrypt($data, $key); // UdP7dXSTp6b5I986PLL8Gs3qH3rMj0SpQ0te4pP7M44=
```

Comment: Be aware that ECB mode is insecure for many uses.  You might want to check that ECB mode is really required, as opposed to CBC, GCM, CTR or some other mode.

Comment: @rossum I know, but it's required, not up to me tbh.

Comment: Why... do you include the key here. I hope you spoofed the key with a false one... and for testing I'd sugest you drop the `base64_encode` part and possibly replace it with `bin2hex`

Comment: @Tschallacka, actualy it's the real one, but what are you going/can do with that? without knowing the service that I'm talking about... But on the other subject you were right, I replaced `base64_encode` with `bin2hex` and it worked. You are welcome to anwser this below and I will accept it when/if you do

Comment: @HulaHula are you sure `BEE361962A1802A7BA2AD328DAE8B291` is a correct output?

Comment: @TejashwiKalpTaru yep, just tested, it's a valid response from the service. Thank you, post the answer please

Comment: @HulaHula I'd suggest strongly that you contact SO that they purge the key from the database and replace it with asterisks or a dummy key. If your service provider performs an audit and finds it here that might spell trouble in the future.

Comment: @Tschallacka, don't worry that's nothing to do with service provider or something like that, it's just a simple web service, but I need it to return a valid response (just a 'true') based on the example I gave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding algorithm returns a stream of bytes back to you of encoded data.

The sample you have doens't provide a base64 encoded variant of the data but a hexadecimal representation.

In your case, just swap out the [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) for [bin2hex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) and the answer should match up.

```
function aes128Encrypt($data, $key) {
  $padding = 32 - (strlen($data) % 32);
  $data .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
  return bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
}
$data = "2874838-49";
$key = "keyshouldbeplacedhere";    
echo aes128Encrypt($data, $key);
```