# How to make PKCS5 and PKCS7 padding with openssl_public_encrypt

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

How to make PKCS5 and PKCS7 padding with `openssl_public_encrypt`?

These are the options:
`OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING`, `OPENSSL_SSLV23_PADDING`, `OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`, `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING`

Comment: I don't get the downvotes?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense as PKCS#5/7 is specified for block ciphers, not asymmetric (public) encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make PKCS5 and PKCS7 padding with openssl_public_encrypt?

`openssl_public_encrypt` is used with asymmetric encryption (encrypting by public key) and indeed only the listed paddings are available.

PKCS7 padding is used with symmetric encryption (openssl_encrypt).

You can pkcs#7 padding with `openssl_encrypt` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php). Apparently (according to the comments) the pkcs#7 padding is used when no option is specified.

<del>Seems in php you will have to it yourself, see [How to add/remove PKCS7 padding from an AES encrypted string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314901/how-to-add-remove-pkcs7-padding-from-an-aes-encrypted-string)</del>

please note - I am not php developer, so if there's better way, please comment / correct.

Comment: The PHP documentation also mentions an option `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`. Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L6534), it seems that standard block padding (PKCS#5) is used, unless zero padding is requested via that `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` option.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek I don't see where the pkcs#5 is implemented, as far I understood if no zero_padding is specified, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA is used (no padding at all). If I am mistaken, feel free to correct me

Comment: It's also mentioned as a comment under the documentation of `openssl_encrypt`:  "Without using `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`, you will automatically get PKCS#7 padding." And: "When OPENSSL_RAW_DATA is specified, the returned data is returned as-is.  When it is not specified, Base64 encoded data is returned to the caller."

Comment: PKCS#5 is the default padding used with OpenSSL if you do not indicate any padding. See [the OpenSSL wiki section on EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#Padding). The `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` option is to select between base64-encoded (the default) and binary (raw) output.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: Interesting read, thanks. I got my information from the [OpenSSL enc app documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/openssl-enc.html), which states "All the block ciphers normally use PKCS#5 padding also known as standard block padding"...

Comment: That link pointed to in the answer relates to `mcrypt` library, which doesn't support PKCS#7 padding. `mcrypt` has been deprecated (possibly also because of some not-too-friendly comments that I made about it).

Comment: Thank you all for feedback - so as far I understood from the commebts, when using `openssl_encrypt` with no options, the PKCS#7 padding is added by default?

Comment: Yes, PKCS#7 padding is added by default. Please adjust the answer so I can change my vote; currently the info in the answer is incorrect.